# I have got the google Client Id How to integrate it with my eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, api, google-plus

//on creation

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        signinButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.signin);
        signinButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        emailLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);

        profileFrame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.profileFrame);
        signinFrame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.signinFrame);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build()).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
    }
```

//connecting google

```
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
```

//on failure

```
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
            return;
        }

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // store mConnectionResult
            mConnectionResult = result;

            if (signedInUser) {
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case RC_SIGN_IN:
            if (responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
                signedInUser = false;

            }
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        signedInUser = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        getProfileInformation();
    }
```

//updating profile

```
    private void updateProfile(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            signinFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            profileFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            signinFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            profileFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

//getting profile info

```
    private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                username.setText(personName);
                emailLabel.setText(email);

                new LoadProfileImage(image).execute(personPhotoUrl);
```

// update profile frame with new info about Google Account
                    // profile

```
                updateProfile(true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateProfile(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.signin:
            googlePlusLogin();
            break;
        }
    }

    public void signIn(View v) {
        googlePlusLogin();
    }

    public void logout(View v) {
        googlePlusLogout();
    }

    private void googlePlusLogin() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            signedInUser = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

    private void googlePlusLogout() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            updateProfile(false);
        }
    }
```

// download Google Account profile image, to complete profile

```
private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask {
        ImageView downloadedImage;

        public LoadProfileImage(ImageView image) {
            this.downloadedImage = image;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String url = urls[0];
            Bitmap icon = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
                icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return icon;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            downloadedImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
```

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We aren't your personal coding service. Learn how to debug your script (*`ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`*), that would tell you exactly what's wrong. My guess being your include files aren't found.

Comment: your select query given only true or false firstly fetch your data and compare in if condition

Comment: missing link identifier $res = mysqli_query("SELECT Password FROM tbl_user WHERE Username='$uname'");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all add error reporting in your file:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

Than note that this condition:

```
if($res==$upass)
```

`$res` will returns the resource id its can not equal to `$upass` because `$upass` is equal to your input field password.

**Second**, read manual for **[mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)** you missed the link identifier in your query like

```
mysqli_query($connectionLink,"Your query");
```

**Third**, how can you compare the password input with database value?

```
$res = mysqli_query($connectionLink, "SELECT Password FROM tbl_user WHERE Username='$uname'");
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($res); // check the records

if($row_cnt){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res); // fetch the data
    if($row['Password'] == $upass){ // check condition (bad practice)
        // your stuff
    }
}
```

**Fourth**, Are you saving simple alphabets in Password field? this is not a good practice, always use encrypted password.

**Password Hashing Manuals:**

**[password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)**  (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)

**[md5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)**

Comment: when i use include_once in my code how could i use connection link in my_sqli method

Comment: @InnovativeDesign: u will get the variable because u are using include no just call it by variable name... read this http://php.net/manual/de/function.include.php...

Comment: <?php
include_once('../includes/connect_database.php'); 
include_once('../includes/variables.php');
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
$uname = $_POST['username'];
$upass = $_POST['password'];
$res = mysqli_query($connect ,"SELECT Password FROM tbl_user WHERE Username='$uname'");

$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($res); // check the records

if($row_cnt){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res); 
    if($row['Password'] == $upass){ 
        echo 'success';}
else{
echo 'failed';
}}}
include_once('../includes/close_database.php'); 
?>

Comment: I changed my code to this still getting blank page and the $connect is in my variables.php file which connects database

Comment: @InnovativeDesign: as i mentioned use error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); at top of the page after <?php and chk errors

Comment: still nothing is displayed

Comment: if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) 
{ 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST); exit;}
else{
echo "nothing in post"} @InnovativeDesign

Comment: test like that, and also show yur form. @InnovativeDesign